# Скрипт выбора по миниатюре не отрабатывает в мобильной версии сайта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Скрипт не отрабатывает в мобильной версии (*на мобильных устройствах, шаблон адаптивный*). Есть миниатюры, которые при клике отображаются в в другом `div`'е с `<img ID=main_img`. В мобильной версии при нажатии на миниатюру выбирается первое изображение, а не нужное.

```
$('.preview a').click(function() {
        way = $(this).children().attr("src");
        console.log(way);
        $('#main_img').attr('src', way);
        function_name();
        return false;
    });
```

При этом в декстопной версии проблем нет. Может влиять fancybox? Помогите разобраться плз.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте этот код

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.preview a').on("click touchstart", function() {
            way = $(this).children().attr("src");
            console.log(way);
            $('#main_img').attr('src', way);
            function_name();
            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: Этот вариант не работает...

Comment: Это одно и тоже, что у автора вопроса

Comment: я обновил код, проверьте сейчас

Comment: Проверил, не работает..

Comment: попробуйте обернуть все документ реади

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.preview a').each(function(){ //найти все вхождения и для каждого
    $(this).on("click tap", function() { // на клик назначить...
        // PUT YOUR CODE HERE ;)
    }
});
```

хотя, вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235794/jquery-mobile-for-every-live-tap-event-should-there-be-an-equivalent-click-even народ пишет, что с "click tap" могут быть проблемы и предлагает использовать сторонний плагин.